# Haskell : Illegal type synonym family application in instance

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass, type-families

I'm working with languages embedded in Haskell. My languages can be printed out as source code, so I created a `Compile` class and made a class instance for every program element that can be printed out. That way I could dump my code compositionally. This worked fine before the concepts of modes was considered.

Each language can be used in two modes (implemented as instances of class `Mode`). In simple mode everything is normal. In named mode a lot of program elements can be replaced with strings. (It works like macro definitions.)

I want to keep all representations type-safe. So program elements of different langauges or different modes cannot be mixed.

So the problem is: how to dump the languages regardless of the mode?

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}
class Compile a where
  comp :: a -> String

-- common elements in all languages
data ElemA l m = ElemA (ElemB l m)
data ElemB l m = ElemB

class Lang l where
  -- language-specific elements
  data Instructions l :: * -> *

-- common modes for all languages
class Mode l m where
  type MElemA l m :: *
  type MElemB l m :: *

-- mode with normal program elements
data SimpleMode
instance Mode l SimpleMode where
  type MElemA l SimpleMode = ElemA l SimpleMode
  type MElemB l SimpleMode = ElemB l SimpleMode

-- a mode where each program element can be replaced with a string
data NamedMode
instance Mode l NamedMode where
  type MElemA l NamedMode = Either String (ElemA l NamedMode)
  type MElemB l NamedMode = Either String (ElemB l NamedMode)

-- definition of Lang1 language
data Lang1
instance Lang Lang1 where
  data Instructions Lang1 m 
    = Add (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m)
    | Mul (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m)
    -- | ...

-- dumping the source code of Lang1 langauge

-- ILLEGAL TYPE SYNONYM FAMILY APPLICATION HERE
instance Compile (MElemA Lang1 m) where  
  comp _ = "A"
-- AND HERE
instance Compile (MElemB Lang1 m) where  
  comp _ = "B"
```

I know that type synonym families does not work well with classes, so I'm looking for another solution.

Possible solutions I'm aware of (but don't want to use):

- Use multiple functions instead of a single polymorphic `comp` function.
- Use only `NamedMode` for representation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A friend of mine, Zoltán Kelemen sent me a solution. He used wrapper classes to encapsulate a program element of a specified language. This way he had eliminated type family applications from the instance heads without more overhead than necessary.

I'm also looking for other solutions.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
class Compile a where
  comp :: a -> String

-- common elements in all languages
data ElemA l m = ElemA (ElemB l m)
data ElemB l m = ElemB

class Lang l where
  -- language-specific elements
  data Instructions l :: * -> *

-- wrapper classes for program elements of Lang1
data Lang1A m = WrapperA (ElemA Lang1 m)
data Lang1B m = WrapperB (ElemB Lang1 m)

-- common modes for all languages
class Mode l m where
  type MElemA l m :: *
  type MElemB l m :: *

-- mode with normal program elements
data SimpleMode
instance Mode l SimpleMode where
  type MElemA l SimpleMode = ElemA l SimpleMode
  type MElemB l SimpleMode = ElemB l SimpleMode

-- a mode where each program element can be replaced with a string
data NamedMode
instance Mode l NamedMode where
  type MElemA l NamedMode = Either String (ElemA l NamedMode)
  type MElemB l NamedMode = Either String (ElemB l NamedMode)

-- definition of Lang1 language
data Lang1
instance Lang Lang1 where
  data Instructions Lang1 m 
    = Add (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m)
    | Mul (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m) (MElemA Lang1 m)
    -- | ...

-- dumping the source code of Lang1 langauge

-- ILLEGAL TYPE SYNONYM FAMILY APPLICATION HERE
instance Compile (Lang1A m) where  
  comp (WrapperA e) = "A"
-- AND HERE
instance Compile (Lang1B m) where  
  comp (WrapperB e) = "B"
```

Comment: Also thanks for mentioning the similarities with this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590495/problem-when-mixing-type-classes-and-type-families?rq=1

Comment: Could have used newtype in place of data - no?