# Typeclass instance with arithmetic constraints on types

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-level-computation

Basically, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
import GHC.TypeLits

newtype Foo (a::Nat) (b::Nat) c = Foo {getFoo :: c}

class Clz a where

instance Clz (Foo a (2*a) c) where
```

I.e., to make `Foo a b` instance of `Clz` only when `a = 2*b`.

I understand that the problem is in the `(2*a)` expression on the last line. When I try to compile it, I get:

```
• Illegal type synonym family application in instance:
    Foo a (2 * a) c
• In the instance declaration for ‘Clz (Foo a (2 * a) c)’
```

Is there a way to overcome this? How would I need to change the syntax? Do I need more language extensions? I am using latest GHC (8.0.1).

Comment: Why not try `instance b ~ (2*a) => Clz (Foo a b c)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a type equivalence constraint (by enabling GADTs or type families):

```
instance (b ~ (2 * a)) => Clz (Foo a b c) where
```

This is a common technique for working with type families as seen in this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2591220/286871). That answer has a bit more explanation: this constraint doesn't mean *exactly* the same thing as the version you wanted, but will probably still work for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, i did not know this usage of `~`.